# Trying to fill a combobox with a dataset

Tags: vb.net, combobox

I am trying to fill a combobox with data from a table. Here is my code:

```
Private Sub btnOverrideGeneralist_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
                                              Handles btnOverrideGeneralist.Click
  With overrideGen
    .cmbOverrideWith.Items.Add(Me.HRSCDataInputDataSet.GeneralistItemNames)

    .txtAssignedRep.Text = txtGeneralist.Text
    .txtOverrideItem.Text = cmbItem.Text
    .txtOverrideTicketNumber.Text = txtTicketNumber.Text

    overrideGen.Show()
  End With       
End Sub
```

But as I click my button, the combobox does not load the data. I have dropped all of the databindings and datasets on to the form. but still not working.

Comment: What if you replace `Me.HRSCDataInputDataSet.GeneralistItemNames` with something else? Does it populate the combo box? If yes, problem with those `GeneralistItemNames`. Try to create a reduced test case for your issue, something we can paste into a brand new project and be able to reproduce it.

Comment: what type is `HRSCDataInputDataSet.GeneralistItemNames`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problems stems from here:

`.cmbOverrideWith.Items.Add(Me.HRSCDataInputDataSet.GeneralistItemNames)`

you are only adding a single item to the form's combobox. Instead loop from your dataset, then add it to the combobox.